# Sum a field only on specific conditions in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to get the amounts from a table where I want to sum some amounts that satisfies a specific condition while retaining the un-summed amount of others if it did not meet the condition.

I was trying this solution but it still doesn't sum up even if it meets the condition.

```
SELECT
  price_type,
  CASE trim(price_type)
    WHEN 'TYPE1' THEN sum(bill_amt)
    ELSE bill_amt
  END bill_amt
FROM (
  SELECT 
    price_type,
    bill_amt
  FROM price_val_tbl
)
GROUP BY price_type, bill_amt
```

Expected Output:

```
PRICE_TYPE   BILL_AMT
==========   ========
TYPE1        50
TYPE2        100
TYPE2        200
```

Actual Output

```
PRICE_TYPE   BILL_AMT
==========   ========
TYPE1        100
TYPE1        -50
TYPE2        100
TYPE2        200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where you want `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT price_type, SUM(bill_amt)
FROM price_val_tbl
WHERE trim(price_type) = 'TYPE1'
GROUP BY price_type
UNION ALL
SELECT price_type, bill_amt
FROM price_val_tbl
WHERE trim(price_type) <> 'TYPE1';
```

The reason you need `UNION ALL` is because you have no unique identifier on each row.  You *could* use a subquery and aggregation like this:

```
SELECT MIN(price_type) as price_type,
       SUM(bill_amt) as billL_amt
FROM (SELECT pv.*, rownum as rn
      FROM price_val_tbl pv
     ) pv
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN trim(price_type) = 'TYPE1' THEN -1 ELSE rn END) ;
```

However, this is less clear on what it is doing.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Never thought of this. Using```UNION ALL``` made sense that it is easier to understand what each query is trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use conditional `GROUP BY` as follows:

```
SQL> SELECT A, SUM(B)
  2  FROM YOUR_DATA
  3  GROUP BY A, ( CASE WHEN A = 'T1' THEN A ELSE TO_CHAR(ROWNUM) END);

A      SUM(B)
-- ----------
T2        100
T2        200
T1         50

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it this would work too but I have too many fields to ```GROUP BY``` and made it harder to read. Not to mention the additional work when you want to update the query and add more ```PRICE_TYPES``` to sum. Upvoting +1.